# Select from a drop down list, form:select, take the first element of the items

Tags: jquery

I got these two forms:

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="idRol" id="Rol">
    <form:option value="1" label="Admin" />
    <form:option value="2" label="User" />
    <form:option value="3" label="Exec" />
    <form:option value="4" label="Manager" />
</form:select>


<form:select class="form-control" path="idEmp" disabled="true" id="idE"> 
    <form:option value="" label="--- Seleccionar ---"/>
    <form:options items="${emp}" />
</form:select>
```

I want, using JQuery, that when I choose X item from the first form, for example admin, exec or manager, to limit the 2nd form to the first item of ${emp}, in case they select User, it will let them pick any of the options of the 2nd form.

I've made this piece of JQuery but, I'm not sure how to access the items of the form when not using the values.

```
$("#Rol").on('change', function() {
    if($("#Rol").val() !== '2') {
        $("#idE").val("Hello World");
        $("#idE").prop("disabled", "true");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#idE").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

I'm fairly new to this area and I'm having trouble, also I'm not exactly sure if I need to use PATH or ID sometimes.

Comment: rol value will be 2 and not user... So `if($("#Rol").val() !== 'User'){` should be `if($("#Rol").val() !== '2'){`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an option to the second select depending on the first one:

```
$("#Rol").on('change', function(){
        if($("#Rol").val() !== '2'){
            $("#idE").append('<option value="hello_world" selected="selected">Hello World</option>');
            $("#idE").prop("disabled", "true");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#idE").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Let's say Hello world is part of ${emp}, so I'm trying to select 1 item of the items 
 in ${emp} for when you choose a value that is not 2, {emp} has the values of a SQL query and I want to fix in place one for 3 roles and let the role user to be able to choose the one he/she wants.

Comment: cn you show an example of the $emp values? The rendered HTML

Comment: crap since I don't know (rendered HTML, sorry for not being helpful): it's a query that takes lets say hello world, invoice, no data, which is the Name attribute of X table from the database and saves it on a List<String> "var" which is returned then addAttribute to emp.

Comment: javascript will use the values in the html you see in your browser when displaying the page (the rendered html) How can you write your code (adn ask for our help) without this info?